# I am not able to correctly transform my annual Data into a time-series using R and the ts() function

Tags: r, time-series

I am currently trying to transform this data into annual time series data ranging from 2000 to 2019. The following is the code I use.

```
WealthShare <- read_excel("WealthShareTop10%.xlsx")
WealthShare_vector <- c(WealthShare$Europe)
WealthShare_ts <- ts(WealthShare_vector, start =c(2000),end = c(2019), frequency =1)
print(WealthShare_ts)
```

The output is the following:

```
Time Series:
Start = 2000 
End = 2019 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 57.82 57.33 54.81 54.74 54.19 54.34 53.75 53.57 53.54 53.13
[11] 53.51 53.76 54.90 56.75 58.46 59.34 59.47 58.73 58.75 58.69
```

I would like to know why its not in the typical ts format. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`stats::ts` will not even allow a `ts` object to be defined with `start` after `end`. You may have some other package attached that defines a new method for `ts`. What other packages do you have attached?

What is your R version (from `R.Version()`)?

What do you get for `methods(ts)`?

What do you see when you enter `ts` at the console and hit enter?

Comment: The strange thing is, for monthly or quarterly data it works fine. Please see my answer below.